# Most efficient way to implement walls and shadows in 2d

Tags: c++, 2d, qt, line-of-sight

I am making a 2d top-down programming game similar to [robocode](http://robowiki.net/wiki/Robocode). There will be up to 1000 walls (lines) in the arena, and up to 50 robots. Each robot can see in a 90 degree arc, and cannot see through walls. I need an efficient way to calculate what each robot can see (other robots and walls). I already have a grid of [bins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_%28computational_geometry%29) implemented. I was wondering what is the most efficient way to tackle this problem.

It would be nice if the method also includes a way to draw the shadows for visualization, but this is not necessary.

I am using C++ and the Qt framework.

**Summary:** The main question is how to generate a list of robots and walls that each robot can see. For example:

```
Robot 1 can see:
    Robot 6
    Robot 15
    A wall from (50,60) to (70,80)

Robot 2 can see:
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'd suggest storing them in some kind of scene graph so that you only have to draw what you can see, and it would be easy to calculate what you can see. And for what they can see, i suggest raycasting or some simplified version of it

Comment: I had thought of this, but with raycasting, the rays spread out. At longer distances, the rays will miss some bins, and consequently, the walls and robots that are contained in those bins.

Comment: You raycast specifically to walls

Comment: Wouldn't that be raytracing if the rays go from the walls to the robot?

Comment: Well you know what walls exist so you cast from the player to each wall within a range

Comment: Ok. Here is what I'm thinking. I calculate an arc of 90 degrees with this algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_drawing_algorithm . The result will be a list of bins that are at a certain distance from the robot. Check for walls and robots in the bins. If there is a wall, don't continue to check behind it. For example, if my vision angle was 0 to 90, and a wall obstructed part of it, my new vision angle might be 0 to 50 and 60 to 90. Keep moving outwards and checking the bins in my vision angle until I do not have any vision angles left.